# Using pyspark binary on AWS lambda function, Error Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark

I'm having issues with my lambda function (python 3.6), the lambda function uses pyspark (spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7 binaries).

As the pyspark binaries are quite big (226 MB zip file), I uploaded the zip file into a S3 bucket. The lambda function will unzips the file into the /tmp folder. After pyspark has been unzipped, permissions are given to the folders and files:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(/tmp/spark):
    for d in dirs:
        os.chmod(os.path.join(root, d), 0o775)
    for f in filenames:
        os.chmod(os.path.join(root, f), 0o775)
```

On the lambda function the SPARK_HOME environment variable has been set with the value /tmp/spark

Also:

```
sys.path.append('/tmp/spark/python')
sys.path.append('/tmp/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip')

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

...
...
sc = SparkContext(appName="ProjectCSV")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
...
...
```

As soon as the SparkContext(appName="ProjectCSV") executes it reports the following error:

```
Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

The PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS environment variable has been added as follow:

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
```

Still reporting the same error.

Any ideas or suggestions, what could be the issue and how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking JAVA_HOME is set in the environment. If not java might not have been installed.